# Symfony component not being installed for Silex

Tags: php, symfony, centos, silex

I have basically done nothing more than

```
$ https://github.com/silexphp/Silex.git
$ cd Silex
$ curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
$ php composer.phar update
```

Always, the same step, and I am getting this error for the fifth time.

[image]

Comment: I just repeated your steps and it worked.  Maybe try again.  Network hiccups are known to happen.

Comment: Weird. I have tried it 5 times. It is not a network problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can increase composers timeout limit in the command line like..

```
COMPOSER_PROCESS_TIMEOUT=1000 php composer.phar update
```

Comment: Well, this is a good suggestion. I will check if this thing works after 16 minutes of wait